# Having issues setting delegate with Observer Pattern

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, observer-pattern

I'm trying to realize the Observer Pattern and I'm experiencing some difficulty as my delegate doesn't seem to be setting properly.

In my Main.storyboard I have a ViewController with a container view. I also have an input box where I'm capturing numbers from a number keypad.

Here's my storyboard:

[image]

I'm trying to implement my own Observer Pattern using a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol PropertyObserverDelegate {
    func willChangePropertyValue(newPropertyValue:Int)
    func didChangePropertyValue(oldPropertyValue:Int)
}
```

My main ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!
    // observer placeholder to be initialized in implementing controller
    var observer : PropertyObserverDelegate?
    var enteredNumber: Int = 0 {

        willSet(newValue) {
            print("//Two: willSet \(observer)") // nil !
            observer?.willChangePropertyValue(5) // hard coded value for testing
        }
        didSet {
            print("//Three: didSet")
            observer?.didChangePropertyValue(5) // hard coded value for testing
        }
    }

    @IBAction func numbersEntered(sender: UITextField) {
        guard let inputString = numberField.text else {
            return
        }
        guard let number : Int = Int(inputString) else {
            return
        }
        print("//One: \(number)")
        self.enteredNumber = number // fires my property observer
    }
}
```

My ObservingViewController:

```
class ObservingViewController: UIViewController, PropertyObserverDelegate {
    // never fires!
    func willChangePropertyValue(newPropertyValue: Int) {
        print("//four")
        print(newPropertyValue)
    }
    // never fires!
    func didChangePropertyValue(oldPropertyValue: Int) {
        print("//five")
        print(oldPropertyValue)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view loads")
        // attempting to set my delegate
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let pvc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
        print("//six \(pvc)")
        pvc.observer = self
    }
}
```

Here's what my console prints:

[image]

**What's happening**

As you can see when my `willSet` fires, my observer is `nil` which indicates that I have failed to set my delegate in my ObservingViewController. I thought I set my delegate using these lines:

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let pvc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    print("//six \(pvc)")
    pvc.observer = self
```

However, I must be setting my delegate incorrectly if it's coming back `nil`.

### Question

How do I properly set my delegate?

Comment: Probably architecture problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34700875/1664443) did reenforce my suspicions which helped me to figure out a solution for assigning my delegate to my view controller properly.

In my `ObservingViewController` I just need to replace the code in my viewDidLoad with the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let vc = app.window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
    vc.observer = self
}
```

Rather than creating a new instance of my view controller, I'm now getting my actual view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling into the storyboard to instantiate a view controller and setting it as the observer, however that instantiates a new instance of that view controller, it doesn't mean that it is referencing the one single "view controller" that is in the storyboard. ObservingViewController needs another way to reference the ViewController that has already been created.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with this... how can I acquire the running instance of my ViewController? Do I have to embed it into a navigation controller?

Comment: You'd have to pass in a reference programmatically